# Google Workflows: How to get part of a string?

Tags: google-workflows

In the following workflow I want to return part of a string, for example:

```
- define:
    assign:
      - value: foobar
- returnValue:
    return: ${value}
```

This would return `foobar` how would I return just `foo`?

Comment: This is a highly requested feature, hopefully, it will be implemented soon. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174365063 until then you need to do it elsewhere like with BigQuery, see this article: https://medium.com/p/54228d166a7d

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now supported under the [text library](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/text/substring).

You can get part of the string using `${text.substring(value), 0, 3}`